# find the difference in substring of timestamp in awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to append some text in /var/log/messages output whenever the timestamp between the two consecutive log is different such as :

previous log: **00:01:5**9 and current log **00:02:0**0
or
previous log:**00:01:4**9 and current log **00:01:5**0

above substring of timestamp if different in consecutive log, append some message to `$0`.

You may run below command it is working for 1 minute, needed it for 10 sec.

```
tail -f /var/log/messages |awk '{split($3,a,":");split($3,b,"");new_time=a[1]":"a[2]":"b[1]; if(prev_time==new_time) print $0; else print "10 Second group is over, starting new: "$0" "prev_time " "new_time }   {split($3,a,":");split($3,b,"");prev_time=a[1]":"a[2]":"b[1]}'
```

Required result is modification of above command to print same message in 10 second gap of logs , currently its doing for 1 minute. I have used split() to capture '`HH:MM:S`" not "`HH:MM:SS`",so whenever privious '`HH:MM:S`" and current '`HH:MM:S`"differ , print the message "`10 Second group is over, starting new: $0`". Not sure what is the mistake here.
In short, currently its working when a minute changes, I need it when second changes from 39 to 40th sec or 09 sec to 10 sec. NOT 11 sec to 12 sec. HH:MM:**S**S , S marked in bold needed to be changed.

Sample lines:

```
Jan 23 15:09:54 foo bar
Jan 23 15:10:04 bla bla
```

Comment: could you paste sample lines from /var/log/messages?

Comment: ... and the expected output too of course. You've been posting here long enough to know this by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the general idea:

```
$ for((i=35;i<45;i++)); do echo Jan 23 00:01:$i; done |  
  awk '{split($3,a,":"); print $0, (p!=(c=int(a[3]/10))?"<<<":""); p=c}'

Jan 23 00:01:35 <<<
Jan 23 00:01:36 
Jan 23 00:01:37 
Jan 23 00:01:38 
Jan 23 00:01:39 
Jan 23 00:01:40 <<<
Jan 23 00:01:41 
Jan 23 00:01:42 
Jan 23 00:01:43 
Jan 23 00:01:44
```

first part is the test data generated for the script since you didn't provide enough.  There is spurious first line match, which can be eliminated with `NR>1` condition but I don't think that's critical.